# Automatically change work item status when release is successful in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, workitem

How to setup linked work items to change status automatically when Release is done.

For example, the state is in DEV and code is deployed with release pipeline to QA branch. I want my work item to change status automatically if the release pipeline is successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add "WorkItem Updater" Extention to your ADO Account. Then add it either in Build/Release Pipeline and set the Status as per your requirement. And better add a value for "WorkItem source" as "WorkItems linked to the Build/Release", then make sure while raising a Pull request, the required Workitem should be tagged along with the Pull request, then only the Task will get Identified the source Workitem then it will change the Status of the User story.

Extension Link & Guide: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater

Comment: Yes, already tried it and that is the solution. Your comment is an answer. Thanks!